# Google Analytics: send Content Grouping without a pageview?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am implementing [Content Grouping](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en#code) on my Wordpress website using the tracking code method.

I understand from the official documentation that the tracking code should be inserted before a pageview, that is,

```
ga('set', 'contentGroup1', 'Blog')
```

alone won't fire but

```
ga('set', 'contentGroup1', 'Blog');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

will. My question is:

**Is there a way to send the grouping information without relying on a pageview?**

I have tried sending an event rather than a pageview, but it didn't work.

I am asking because I am using a Wordpress plugin to inject the default GA tracking code, and I would like not to mess with it.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content groupings *can* be applied to events, and not just pageviews. When you send in an event hit, you can go to the Events > Pages reports to see if a particular page associated with an event falls into a specific content grouping.

One of the caveats is that the content groupings report under Site Content > All Pages report is different from the Events > Pages report. The former categorizes only pageviews, whereas the latter categorizes pages associated with an event.

Note that if you use the 'set' method to set the content group as you've done before the pageview hit, all subsequent hits for the page (events, pageviews, transactions, etc.) will be associated with the specified content group (ie. "Blog").

Comment: Thank you very much, nyuen! I do see the populated content groups in the events reports.

I was not aware that the information given via the `set` method would end up in different buckets, depending on whether it was sent with a pageview or an event.

What is the best method, in your opinion, event or pageview? In particular, are the dimensions & metrics associated to content groups (eg. `ga.previousContentGroupXX`, see [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=content_grouping)) propagated also when the information is sent via an event?

Comment: Just added clarification to my answer. So when you use the 'set' method, the subsequent hits that you send will be associated with the content group you've set. There isn't really a best method in my opinion - it's more like what would you like to see in your reports. I'm not sure if the dimensions and metrics associated with content groups propagate, but I would tend to think so because content groupings data is merely in addition to what you are already sending to GA, and not altering data being sent.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! I have accepted your answer.